# What's the command-line equivalent of creating a new Partition through MS Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage, windows-command-prompt

For example,

When I connect LUNs to a given server, I go into Windows Management, right click on a new disk, and click New Partition.

Given Windows CMD prompt, how can I accomplish the same thing the Wizard does via cmd-line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diskpart is the command line utility that you'll need to use. The following link has an in depth description and usage instructions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415